# Has any scholar systematically categorized the types of bias found in sources?

Tags: methodology

I am preparing a lesson on bias in historical writings.

I have identified different causes of bias, for example:

- Primary source written from by someone wanting to exaggerate their own accomplishments.
- Secondary source written by a descendant.
- Book commissioned by a town museum honoring the town's namesake.
- A personal enemy writing negatively about someone.

There are also different ways the bias can manifest itself:

- Soldiers exaggerating size of their enemy and enemy units killed.
- Primary source neglecting to include servants or slaves in a list of people involved in an event.
- Secondary source skips over events that shows a historical hero in a negative light.

My concern is I'm missing many potential types of bias. There are tons of lists on-line, but they're never comprehensive or organized. I'm wondering if there is a leading scholar in this subject who has come up with a comprehensive way to categorize or classify bias?

Comment: I'd wonder if it was even *possible*.  It seems like "motivations for bias" would be nearly as wide-spanning as "motivations".  It's a bit difficult to be comprehensive on something that extensive that's also that vague.

Comment: @BenBarden Maybe they won't be able to list everything, but at least create categories or naming conventions under which most or all types will fall?